# Making a single image to scroll infinitely over the viewcontroller?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch

I have two images. first one is something like a transparent hole and should be static while the second one is scooter like image which needs to continuously scrolling horizontally that should give a effect of video.

Can anybody suggest me what to do to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can animate X position of your image view like this:

```
CGPoint point0 = imView.layer.position;
CGPoint point1 = { NSIntegerMax, point0.y };

CABasicAnimation *anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position.x"];
anim.fromValue    = @(point0.x);
anim.toValue  = @(point1.x);
anim.duration   = 1.5f;
anim.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn];

// First we update the model layer's property.
imView.layer.position = point1;

// Now we attach the animation.
[imView.layer  addAnimation:anim forKey:@"position.x"];
```

For infinite scrolling, set your scrollview' `contentSize` correctly:

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(NSIntegerMax, kScreenHeight); // Deduce kScreenHeight based on device height
```

Comment: I want somethig like apple [streetscoller] (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/StreetScroller/Introduction/Intro.html)project. In the project they have provide with infinite horizontal scrolling but i require autoscroll like option, which will solve my problem

Comment: You can try with my edited post. Basically, set the second point' X value as infinite and also set scroll view's contentSize width to infinite. Try and let me know if this works for you. @AnujVats

Answer (score 0):

Please check the code [Infinity Scroll](https://github.com/Seitk/InfiniteScrollPicker)